# What the definition for "Itsy Bitsy" term?

Tags: meaning, terminology

Like on the *Itsy Bitsy Spider* I heard it in some lyrics but I don't know what this mean indeed.

Comment: Have you looked up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Itsy bitsy" simply mean "tiny" or "very small".

Comment: I had an answer ready when it was closed, so I'll post it here.

Comment: It's the conventional way of representing (supposed) children's language, like *Gramma* for *Grandmother*. *"Itsy bitsy"* and *"teeny weeny"* both mean 'very small'. The first is (supposedly) from *little bit* and the other is from reduplicated and vowel-raised *tiny*.

Comment: I.e, supposedly the sequence went from *a little bit of X* as a quantifier, to *little bitty X* as an intensified adjective, to *itsy bitsy X* as a juvenile version.

Comment: *Teeny weeny* went from *tiny* to *teeny* to *teeny tiny* to *teeny weeny*. Perhaps. Nobody was taking note at the time.

Comment: In any event, *itsy bitsy* is a fixed phrase, with its own famous song.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Yes, [the song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itsy_Bitsy_Teenie_Weenie_Yellow_Polka_Dot_Bikini) is pretty famous, but sadly [Brian Hyland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Hyland) is pretty much forgotten, and all the [covers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itsy_Bitsy_Spider) get the words all wrong.

Comment: It's a folk song; there isn't any way to get the words "wrong". There are lots of variants of any folk song. As Duke Ellington put it, "If it sounds good, it **is** good."

Comment: @JohnLawler - Nonsense, as covers of *Itsy Bitsy Teenie Weenie Yellow Polka Dot Bikini* ("the song" in my link:) none of those *Itsy Bitsy Spider* covers come close.

Comment: I didn't listen to the link; _Itsy Bitsy Teenie Weenie Yellow Polka Dot Bikini_ is a copyrighted popular song, and not the original source of either phrase. _The Itsy Bitsy Spider_, on the other hand, **is** a folk song, and there are lots of versions.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Yes, I was well aware of all those facts before I posted the three links to wikipedia articles, and in fact knew that the pre-1960 covers of *Itsy Bitsy Spider* could not be covers of  1960 copyrighted popular song "Itsy Bitsy Teenie Weenie Yellow Polka Dot Bikini" which is described in first link.  The third link discusses several versions of folk song *Itsy Bitsy Spider* from early and mid 1900's.  Naturally, when you wrote "*itsy bitsy* is a fixed phrase, with its own famous song" I assumed you were referring to one of the above songs.